# Xcode 8: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, linker, ibm-mobilefirst, x86-64, xcode8

I am developing a hybrid application on Worklight. After upgrade from Xcode 7.3.1. to Xcode 8, I started getting the following error messages when tried to generate the XCarchive or Build and run the App on the Simulator.

MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0

***Configurations used:***

**Architectures:**   *Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)*

**Valid Architectures:**  *armv7, armv7s, arm64*

**Error Log from Xcode:**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/hjimenez/Documents/eclipseKepler - Build 3.1.0/ITS/apps/ITS/iphone/native/WorklightSDK"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/hjimenez/Documents/eclipseKepler - Build 3.1.0/ITS/apps/ITS/iphone/native/Tealeaf"'
ld: library not found for -lWorklightStaticLibProject
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have a .cpp or .mm file in your project?  (Xcode ignores the standard library unless it sees a reason to include it.)

Comment: No, I don't have .cpp nor .mm files in the project.

Comment: Add one, even if it does nothing.  I think it's necessary for the linker to reference the standard library.

Comment: Thank you Phillip for your comment. I update the post with the current messages that I am getting. I fixed some errors adding resources in the "Build Phases" tab.

Comment: What is your mobilefirst version?

Comment: MobileFirst 6.3.0

Comment: @HelenoJimenez Try with Adding `$(SRCROOT)/frameworks` in your Frameworks Search Path under Build Settings of your Xcode Project Else please provide issue re-creatable sample.

Comment: @VittalPai I have the following configuration in Frameworks Search Path

$(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)" "$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks"

Comment: @HelenoJimenez Can you please share me the issue re-creatable sample ? I can see spaces in your project absolute path `Documents/eclipseKepler - Build 3.1.0/ITS/apps/`, Might be this could be the reason .

Comment: @HelenoJimenez, did you try vittal's suggestion?

Comment: I fix the issue adding the following Resources into "Build Phases" tab.

*UIKit.Framework*
*libstdc++.6.tbd*

Comment: @HelenoJimenez Thanks. I pasted your text as an answer. Feel free to write it also yourself to get credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I fixed the issue adding the following Resources into "Build Phases" tab:
>
> - UIKit.Framework
> - libstdc++.6.tbd
>
> Also is probable that you need to remove the following resources from "Build Phases" tab, (but first try the fix above):
>
> - libc++.dylib
> - libstdc++.dylib